# class template has already been defined

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class that inherits a class, which inherits from another class. In this base class is a template.

Two classes inherit from this base class, and then two more classes each inherit from one or the other class. I am getting a 'class template has already been defined' compile error when I am trying to incorporate the buttons I have created into a menu. It will compile if I only include one of the button types, but if I compile with both files included I get the error.

The base class of all the buttons

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

namespace eng
{
namespace UI
{
    template<class EventTemplate> 
    class ButtonBase
    {

    protected:

        bool hasBeenClicked;

        typename EventTemplate myEvent;

        sf::Sprite mySprite;

    public:

        ButtonBase();

        virtual bool CheckIfUsed(int mouseX, int mouseY, bool mouseClicked, bool mouseReleased) = 0;

        EventTemplate GetButtonEvent();

        sf::Sprite *GetSprite();

    };
};
};
```

The base class for radio buttons

```
#pragma once

#include "Button Base.h"

namespace eng
{
namespace UI
{
    template<class EventTemplate>
    class RadioButton : public ButtonBase<EventTemplate>
    {

    protected:

        enum ButtonState {MouseOutside, MouseOver, On, Off} myState;

    public:

        RadioButton();

        virtual bool CheckIfUsed(int mouseX, int mouseY, bool mouseClicked, bool mouseReleased) = 0;

        void TurnOff();

    };
};
};
```

The two classes intended to be used as instances.

```
#pragma once

#include "Radio Button.h"

namespace eng
{
namespace UI
{

    template<class EventType>
    class RoundRadioButton : public RadioButton<EventType>
    {

    private:

        sf::Rect myArea; 

    public:

        RoundRadioButton(double setx, double sety, double setRadius, sf::Image &setImage, EventType setEvent);

        bool CheckIfUsed(int mouseX, int mouseY, bool mouseClicked, bool mouseReleased);
    };
};
};


#pragma once

#include "Radio Button.h"

namespace eng
{
namespace UI
{
    template<class EventType>
    class RoundRadioButton : public RadioButton<EventType>
    {

    private:

        double myCenterX;
        double myCenterY;

        double myRadius;

    public:

        RoundRadioButton(double setx, double sety, double setRadius, sf::Image &setImage, EventType setEvent);

        bool CheckIfUsed(int mouseX, int mouseY, bool mouseClicked, bool mouseReleased);
    };
};
};
```

The class that includes the two radio button types.

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

#include "Round Radio Button.h"
#include "Rectangular Radio Button.h"

namespace eng
{
namespace UI
{
    template<class EventType>
    class RadioButtonMenu
    {

    private:

        RadioButton<EventType> *myCurrentChoice;

        std::vector< RadioButton<EventType>* > myButtons;

    public:

        RadioButtonMenu();
        ~RadioButtonMenu();

        void SetParameters(std::vector< RadioButton<EventType> > *setButtons, RadioButton<EventType> *defaultSelection);

        void CheckMouseAction(double mousex, double mousey, bool mouseClicked, bool mouseReleased);

        EventType GetSelection();
    };
};
};
```

If I leave out one of the radio button includes, the error goes away. I looked this up in a search and it has been solved using #pragma once or #ifndef but I'm already doing that. I've been reading about templates more as this is my first real attempt at using them but I'm having difficulty understanding it. Any help solving this problem or with templates in general would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Both of your derived classes are named `RoundRadioButton`?

Comment: LOL OOPS! That is actually the entire problem! It is suppose to be a round button and a rectangle button. I'm going to delete this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are violating One Definition Rule (ODR) as you create two templates of the same name (RadioButtonMenu) with different definitions. Give them different names or merge them into one template as they only seem to differ in private (implementation) part and have the same interface.

Comment: See comment in the question. I was overlooking the fact that I had intended to have a round button and a rectangle button, but had actually made two round buttons. My eye just never caught this.